# Sublime text 3 fails to compile

Tags: pdftex, miktex, sublime-text

I am getting the following message after trying to build

```
[Compiling C:\Users\my name\Desktop\TeX\untitled-1.tex]

TraditionalBuilder: Engine: pdflatex -> pdftex. Invoking texify... 

COULD NOT COMPILE!

Attempted command:texify -b -p --engine=pdftex --tex-option="--synctex=1" untitled-1.tex
Build engine: Traditional Builder
```

I have installed Latextools, and I am using SumatraPDF

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just to eliminate sublime, have you tried compiling manually via a command prompt?

Comment: From reading your other question, I think you simply have not installed latex on your computer. You only have the tools needed to **write** the code for a latex doc, not the tools needed to compile it into a PDF. This is why I ask you to try to compile by hand. If latex is missing on the computer, that will fail as well and you'll know what is wrong. Try to just start a comnand prompt and run the command: pdflatex

Comment: Thanks for the reply
I might have forgotten to mention, but i have installed MiKTeX, compiling PDFs through MiKTeX works well

Comment: I just ran pdflatex through cmd prompt, It didn't work.

Comment: Then what exactly do you mean by compiling through miktex works well? That statement require more information

Comment: When i typeset it on MiKTeX, it displays an pdf to the right

Comment: Miktex does not typeset anything on its own and does not display a pdf. Exactly what did you do? Which programme?

Comment: I've added two images which should make it easier for me to explain, i open "TeXworks", and typesetting gives me the result on the right tab

The picture above shows what happends when i press CTRL+B [build] in sublime text

Comment: That is the texworks editor. It has nothing to do with miktex, just gets installed along side it such that new users always have a latex capable editor at hand. My bet is that if you look in the texworks settings, the path to pdflatex is written in full, ie full path c:/.... But in sublime it just says pdflatex and sublime relies on the path being set correctly. We have already established that your path is not set correctly, otherwise pdflatex in comnand prompt would have worked. Either write the path to pdflatex and friends in sublime in full as they are in texworks

Comment: Or seek help in figuring out why the path is wrong. For the later I cannot help I'm not a Windows user, nor a miktex user.

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow the README and run the "Reconfigure and migrate settings" command? (Using the Command Palette is probably the quickest way to do so---just search for the above command).

Comment: Hello, it works for me, it compiles the .tex file, but does not open it automatically in Sumatra.. When I double click the generated file it opens, but I would like it to open automatically.. Any ideas?

Comment: Again, see the README. The latest release does attempt to find Sumatra, by searching the default paths it is installed to, so everything may just work now.